# Nginx Upload Module for Django REST framework

Tags: django, docker, nginx, file-upload, django-rest-framework

I want to upload large files to my djangos MEDIA folder using the nginx upload module.

The Django REST "POST" endpoint for the single file upload is at

http://localhost:1337/api/record/measurements/#id/upload/

where #id can be an integer (1,2,3,4,5...), and works for django without nginx.

I wrote the nginx config

```
    #/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://django-app:8000;
    }

    location  /api/record/measurements/1/upload/ {
        error_page 418 = @upload;
        if ($request_method = POST ) {
            return 418;
        }
        include /etc/nginx/mainloc.conf;
    }

    location @upload {
        upload_pass   @backend;
        upload_store /vol/web/media/_upload 1;
        upload_store_access user:r;
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.name "$upload_file_name";
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.content_type "$upload_content_type";
        upload_set_form_field $upload_field_name.path "$upload_tmp_path";
        upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.md5" "$upload_file_md5";
        upload_aggregate_form_field "$upload_field_name.size" "$upload_file_size";
        upload_pass_form_field "^submit$|^description$";
        upload_cleanup 400 404 499 500-505;

    }


    location / {
        include /etc/nginx/mainloc.conf;
    }
```

with

```
#mainloc.conf
proxy_pass http://django-app:8000;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_redirect off;
```

## Edit:

I managed to upload the file to /vol/web/media/_upload, but after the file upload is complete, I get the response

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "data": null
}
```

and the uploaded File is not moved to the final location
    MEDIA=/vol/web/media/ but remains in *upload_store*

Comment: what are you expecting to be different? Basically the nginx upload module should make it possible to upload really large files without failing on the gunicor/uwsgi side of things. If it's still working, that means you've succeeded. It's not going to speed up anything.

Comment: But is there no way to make sure that it really works? For example, the folder and subfolder that I have as upload_store are always empty, even during and after an upload. I thought that nginx would write directly to them

Comment: I agree the temp upload folder should have the file while it's being uploaded, yes. After the upload it would be empty, since the file has been processed by then. But why do you have `location /` as the first entry? It should be the last entry.

Comment: I moved the location / to the last entry, but I'm afraid it didn't change anything regarding the empty temp upload folders

Comment: you could add a custom header to your @test location and print it in your django code to check that the /upload-data settings are indeed being used. I don't really know why you don't see the file temporarily appearing in your upload location.

Comment: if I give a different custom header to both locations / and /upload-data, I see the header given to "/" also at http://localhost:1337/api/record/measurements/1/upload-data . Does the expression somehow not match?

Comment: do you use file upload parser?